# Backbone "add" and "update" events confusion

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, marionette

From the Backbone.js (1.2.3) documentation:

> **add** *collection.add(models, [options])*
>
> Add a model (or an array of models) to the collection, firing an "add"
> event for each model, and an "update" event afterwards.

In my code I want to add a new model ([visually a card with an input](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13639/)) to the collection and then force focus on the input of created card. I'm not sure if it's the correct way, but I basically listen to the event fired when model is added to collection and trigger another event which facilitates focusing from the view of created model:

```
# ItemView
initialize: ->
    App.vent.on "focus:field", =>
        $("div.card:last").addClass("edit")
        @$el.find("input:first").focus()
```

When I listen to the `update` event, it works as expected: `:last` card (the new model) is selected and input is focused.

But when I listen to the `add` event, `initialize` function fires on the penultimate model, instead of the new model. The new model is still created, but the `edit` class and focus is forced on the one before.

Why is that happens?

I would use an `update` event for this purpose, but unfortunately for me `model.destroy` method also fires an `update` event, so it results in ruined UI, and if I pass `model.destroy` with `silient:true` bad things happen overall. Is there a workaround?

Relevant code:

```
# CompositeView
class List.Models extends App.Views.CompositeView
    template: "path/to/template"
    childViewContainer: "div.destination"
    childView: List.Model
    events: 
        "click #add-model": "addModel"

    initialize: ->
        @listenTo @collection, "update", ->
            App.vent.trigger "focus:field"

    addModel: (e) ->
        @$el.find("#add-model").prop "disabled", true
        model = App.request "new:model:entity"
        @collection.add(model)

# ItemView
class List.Model extends App.Views.ItemView
    template: "path/to/template"

    initialize: ->
        App.vent.on "focus:field", =>
            $("div.card:last").addClass("edit")
            @$el.find("input:first").focus()
```

**Edit:**
Apparently the difference between `add` and `update` events is that the `add` event is fired immediately after `@collection.add(model)` is called, but before new model is inserted in the DOM, resulting in `$("div.card:last")` selector pointing to the penultimate view. I'm not sure however, maybe more experienced people can clarify whether this is true or not. I've come to this conclusion after adding timeout to the execution of the App.vent:

```
initialize: ->
    delay = (ms, func) -> setTimeout func, ms
    # Triggered via add event
    App.vent.on "focus:field", =>
        delay 100, =>
            $("div.card:last").addClass("edit")
            $("input:first").focus()
```

Comment: _initialize function fires on the penultimate model.._ What is the **penultimate model**?  Could you post all relevant code?

Comment: @hindmost, please take a look on this [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13639/), it illustrates what I mean by penultimate model. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Still unclear. Furthermore I don't see any Backbone code there.

Comment: @hindmost, I've update the question with more code.

Comment: @curious_gudleif  *"but before new model is inserted in the DOM"* - Backbone doesn't insert anything into the DOM. You should be doing that yourself. So it's easy to set it as focused where you're creating the new Element corresponding to the new model.